# Creating a column in R which is based in information in other columns

Tags: r

My data set consists of the columns CODE, FIRE, CARBON, and DEPTH
example of data in the column CODE are chic, chiq, lopc, lopq etc.

Besides this I got information in which is mentioned that each value, chic for example, in the column CODES belongs to either A, B or C.

So I want to create in R a new column which is based on the CODE column. So that when I say to R that when CODE is for example chic, the value in the new column is A on the same row.

I hope someone could help me with this,

Thanks in advance!

( I wanted to insert a column in here with an example of the data, but it didnt work, I hope it is now also clear what I want to create)

Comment: what you tried til now?

Comment: Please take the time to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. This will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
yourdata$newcolumn<-sapply(as.character(yourdata$CODE),
                           switch,
                           "chic"="A","code2"="B","code3"="C")
```

Of course, you'll need to adapt the code to your data but you didn't give a lot of details...

**Example** :

with `yourdata` the below data.frame :

```
   CODE FIRE CARBON      DEPTH
1  chic    1      3 -1.3107045
2 code2    1      3  1.0781249
3 code3    1      3 -0.6762211
4  chic    1      3  0.9196376
5 code2    2      4 -0.7161380
6 code2    2      4 -0.5506980
7  chic    2      4  0.3323771
8  chic    2      4 -0.4131832
```

you get the new data.frame `yourdata` :

```
   CODE FIRE CARBON      DEPTH newcolumn
1  chic    1      3 -1.3107045         A
2 code2    1      3  1.0781249         B
3 code3    1      3 -0.6762211         C
4  chic    1      3  0.9196376         A
5 code2    2      4 -0.7161380         B
6 code2    2      4 -0.5506980         B
7  chic    2      4  0.3323771         A
8  chic    2      4 -0.4131832         A
```

Comment: thank you! that is the output I want to create! only when I apply it to my data frame, I get the following error: In FUN(X[[174L]], ...) : EXPR is a "factor", treated as integer.

Comment: @Jordy, can you provide your data (with `dput(yourdata)`) ? It's really hard to reproduce an error without the data...

Comment: @Jordy, but you can try my function, with `sapply(as.character(yourdata$CODE),...)` and that will probably work if the problem is indeed that CODE is a factor (I edited my answer to modify the call)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use (assuming your data is a in a dataframe `df`)...

```
df$NEW[df$CODE == "chic"] <- "A"
df$NEW[df$CODE == "chiq"] <- "B"

df
#   CODE DEPTH CARBON FIRE  NEW
# 1 chic     0   24.2    U    A
# 2 chic    10   25.6    U    A
# 3 chiq     0   20.3    B    B
# 4 chiq     0   50.3    B    B
# 5 chiq    10   40.5    B    B
# 6 chiq    20   24.2    B    B
# 7 polc     0   60.5    U <NA>
# 8 polc    10   10.2    U <NA>
# 9 polq     0   20.5    U <NA>
```

etc...

To recode multiple values at once, use `%in%` and a vector for example:

`df$NEW[df$CODE %in% c("chic", "chiq")] <- "A"`

Comment: Thank you for helping! I tried your method, only I get the following error message: Error in carbon2$NEW[carbon2$CODE == "ACHIQ", "ACHIC", "INKAQ", "INKAC",  : incorrect number of subscripts

Comment: It looks like your code is incomplete in your comment. Are you trying to recode multiple values at the same time?

Comment: Yes, example of what i did is,
carbon2$NEW[carbon2$CODE == "ALFQ","ALFC","SUNCHQ"] <- "A"
carbon2$NEW[carbon2$CODE == "CHALLQ", "CHALLC", "LAGQ"] <- "B"
carbon2$NEW[carbon2$CODE == "ACHIQ", "ACHIC", "INKAQ"] <- "C"

Comment: To do that you will need to use `%in%` and pass a vector. So, `carbon2$NEW[carbon2$CODE %in% c("ALFQ", "ALFC", "SUNCHQ")] <- "A"`